# ZPL ^DN command?

Tags: zpl, zpl-ii, zebra

I have a ZPL file which contains an image represented in ASCII data.

```
^GFA,...parameters and ascii data...
     ...
00000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000
^DN
^XZ
```

However I cannot find anything about the `^DN` command. Starting with a caret.

The regular command is `~DN` (starting with a tilde).

Is this a ZPL dialect, brand specific extension or something undocumented?

Comment: That's just wrong - but it works anyway, because anything with a tilde or caret would end the ASCII hex data.

Comment: I would assume it is synonymous to `~DN`. Technically wrong, but [probably acceptable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle). There are commands that do different things based on the prefix, DN does not appear to be one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extend on SyndRain's fast first answer:

First you have the `^GFA` command, which specifies the download (`^GF`) of
"ASCII hexadecimal" compressed (`A`) graphic field data.

The data is interpreted in a special way, where *caret* or *tilde* are abort-signals:

> ASCII hexadecimal data: 00 to FF
> A string of ASCII hexadecimal numbers, two digits per image byte. CR and LF
> can be inserted as needed for readability. The number of two-digit number
> pairs must match the above count. Any numbers sent after count is satisfied
> are ignored. A comma in the data pads the current line with 00 (white space),
> minimizing the data sent. `~DN` or any **caret** or **tilde** character **prematurely aborts the download**.

See: [ZPL 2 Command Reference](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra_new_ia/en-us/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf#page=211), page 211

So, as already commented by others, the `^DN` you encounter is probably an intended abort using not entirely correct syntax (`~DN` would be more correct).

Answer (score 2):

It is the **Abort Download Graphic** command:

> Description: After decoding and printing the number of bytes in parameter t of the ~DG command, the printer returns to normal Print Mode. Graphics Mode can be aborted and normal
> printer operation resumed by using the ~DN command.
>
> Comments: If you need to stop a graphic from downloading, you should abort the
> transmission from the host device. To clear the ~DG command, however, you must send a ~DN
> command.

---

Edit: I miss-read OP's question so this only answered what is `~DN`, but for the completeness of [hcdev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77579783/9107694), I'll keep this answer here.